# keys stored in list and using them in keyExtractor

Tags: list, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a nested object and I extracted the keys and values  using Object.keys and Object.values and storing them under 'keys' and 'arrayData' below. I can't figure out how to use keyExtractor with the list of keys ('keys') I have created to match the array. Any ideas?

[nested object from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw6m7.png)

```
let data = this.props.jobHistory
let keys = Object.keys(data)
let arrayData = Object.values(data)

 <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => keys[index]} //I thought this would work but it is printing nothing
      data={arrayData}
      renderItem={({item}) => {
        return (
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(item)}{"\n"}</Text>
        )}
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

keyExtractor does not present or print any actual data, it only provides a "key" that's used by RN to differentiate components. It's an invisible value. Assuming every value in keys is unique, this should not return any errors. If you want to verify that the correct key is bring paired to the correct item when printed, you can do

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => console.log(`${keys[index]}:${arrayData{index}}`);keys[index]} //I thought this would work but it is printing nothing
```